# block diagonal matrix armadillo

Tags: c++, rcpp, armadillo

I'm trying to build a block diagonal matrix out of a `field` (List) object in `Armadillo`. My code compiles but hangs:

```
    // [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat blockDiag( arma::field<mat> x ) {

//x: list of matrices 

unsigned int n = x.n_rows ;
int dimen = 0 ;
arma::ivec dimvec ;

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        dimvec[i] = x(i,0).n_rows ; 
        dimen += dimvec[i] ;
    }

mat X(dimen,dimen,fill::zeros);
int idx=0;

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        X.submat( idx, idx, idx + dimvec[i] - 1, idx + dimvec[i] - 1 ) = x(i,0) ;
        idx = idx + dimvec[i] ;
    }

    return(X);
}
```

Comment: You need to initialize dimvec with the right size, i.e. arma::ivec dimvec(n);

Comment: @johanmaack thank you again, I though that only instantiation of the variable was required.

Comment: Your `blockDiag()` function has a performance problem: it's passing the `x` variable by copying. This is quite expensive for `field<mat>` objects. To avoid the copy, change the function declaration to use a reference: `blockDiag(arma::field<mat>& x)`. Note the extra `&`. Everything else stays the same, including usage/calling of the function.

Comment: @ mtall in which cases it is safe to use `&` if you use the name `x` as a variable in different functions?

Answer (score 4):

As johanmaack suggested, the main problem is that the `dimvec` vector doesn't have the right size. Your code is simply trashing memory, leading to a crash. 
Changing `arma::ivec dimvec` to `arma::ivec dimvec(n)` solves this.

However, your code has another problem, in that you are likely to make the same or similar mistake again.  Your code is currently accessing the elements of `dimvec` through the [] operator, which doesn't have bounds checks. This is why no error was reported. Instead, use the [() operator](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#element_access) which has bounds checks in Armadillo. In other words, change `dimvec[i]` to `dimvec(i)`. Disable the bounds checks only when you are sure that your code works correctly.